# gsettings: no change after configuring settings

Tags: unity, proxy, gsettings

I have a system running Ubuntu 14.04.1. I would like to set the proxy settings globally via `gsettings`, but unfortunately I can't seem to change anything. I run the following command as root:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode manual
```

When I try to retrieve the configuration, the mode is still set to `'none'`:

```
# gsettings get org.gnome.system.proxy mode
'none'
```

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: Try to restart the computer.

Comment: That doesn't change anything (I've tested it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `gsettings` only changes the settings for the user who owns the X session that `$DISPLAY` points to. If you use `sudo` that's your current user. You can see that by the file `$HOME/.config/dconf/user` being modified.

To change the default settings for all users create the file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.system.proxy.gschema.override` with the content

```
[org.gnome.system.proxy]
mode="manual"
```

Then run

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Comment: *Running gsettings only changes the settings for root.*  Not on my system(s), OP's command works perfectly here.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm: The command actually doesn't change the settings for root but the settings for the user who owns the X session that `$DISPLAY` points to. If you use `sudo` that's the calling user (fixed that in my answer). It doesn't change any global settings so the settings for other users  don't change.

Comment: You should never change things in /usr/*. I'm almost sure there is a way do these changes in /etc/*.

Comment: @Bachsau . Please could you elaborate how you would implement these changes in /etc/* ? Are you referencing creating a plain text keyfile in `/etc/dconf/db/database.d/` directory, and a corresponding 'lock' file, as per https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators, as I cannot get this to work https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038184/…. – case_2501 4

Comment: @FlorianDiesch . I do not believe this will work with the quotation marks around the key value, i.e. "manual". At least it does not for me, and returns the following error when `sudo glib-compile-schemas.....` is run: '0-7:can not parse as value of type 'b'. Ignoring override for this key'. Removing the quotation marks resolves this issue.