# Ubuntu Mate config file for the dashboard

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I would like to configure the default Mate dashboard for all the new users of a computer. I want to add launchers for some applications.

At first I'm not able to find any file that store the content of the dashboard. And then I was planning on using a dconf profile (as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037553/how-to-configure-a-dconf-key-globally-across-all-user-accounts)) but I don't know the right key to set the dashboard applications.

Comment: It will not be possible to do that "at once" for already existing users. This requires editing of each individual user profile. Defaults in effect when creating new users, however, could be changed.

Comment: @vanadium yes I want to do it when new users are created (sorry, it wasn't explicite). How do you do that ?

Comment: Use "edit" to change the question and make it more clear. Not all readers will read through the comments. I do not know the specifics.