# How to ‘lockdown’ system-wide settings with `dconf`

Tags: gnome, usb, automount, dconf

I want to ‘lockdown’ a particular key/value combination in `dconf`, so that only superusers will be able to modify that particular setting. In order to achieve this it is necessary to add a ‘lock’ to the system database, so that no equivalent key/value listed in a higher order database (in the `dconf` profile) can take precedence.

For a detailed explanation of the concept of a `dconf` profile and the related ‘key files’ please see the Gnome System Administrators [Wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators).

From the System Admin Wiki:

> Lockdown is supported by creating a 'locks' subdirectory in the key file directory (ie: /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks). The files contained in this  directory contain a list of keys to lock, one per line.

My keyfile directory shows as ‘ibus.d’, as opposed to ‘local.d’ given in the example:

`:/etc/dconf/db/ibus.d$`

By checking the `dconf` profile `/etc/dconf/profile/ibus`, this would appear correct:

Contents of 'ibus' file: `user-db:user \ system-db:ibus`

**As per the Wiki**:

1. Create an appropriate key file:

   `==> /etc/dconf/db/ibus.d/00-media-handling ==<`

   `[org/gnome/desktop/media-handling]`

   `automount=false`
2. Create a ‘locks’ subdirectory and add an appropriate file:

   `==> /etc/dconf/db/ibus.d/locks/00_media-handling-lock ==<`

   `/org/gnome/desktop/media-handling/automount`

In my case I have set, and locked, the `automount` key, for the `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling` schema, to 'false'.

Finally run `sudo dconf update`. For good measure I also reboot the machine.

The expected behaviour, upon attaching a USB drive, would be for the device not to automount. This, however, is not the case. If I attach a USB drive and run `df`:

`/dev/sdb1  983344  192 983152  1%  /media/user/xxxx-xxxx`

Assuming I am at fault; I have started from ‘scratch’ numerous times, each time following the (identical) instructions from varied sources, including examples given on this site; example [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database) and [two](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132175/how-to-store-a-dconf-key-as-read-only#132184). 
Each time to no avail. Please could you kindly enlighten as to where I could be going wrong?
(Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: I've never seen that work properly in Ubuntu, ever.

Comment: @doug thank you. I honestly cannot see what I am doing wrong, and I have read numerous articles and started afresh numerous times. If this does not work, should it not be reported as a bug?

Comment: I think I did a couple of years ago, I'll have a look in LP. As I remember I tried every which way I could find, had absolutely no effect..

Comment: Can't find, either I didn't or it was closed for inactivity, was a couple of years ago. If you file add link here. ( note that bugs are best filed on development version though you could file on bionic, tag cosmic.

Comment: Take a look here, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1122028 & here, https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=693149 Maybe something to help you??

Comment: @doug thanks for looking. I've spent an inordinate amount of time trying to get this to work, very frustrating. If I report as a bug, I'll be sure to update. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The profile file must be /etc/dconf/profile/user

From man 7 dconf:

```
On startup, dconf consults the DCONF_PROFILE environment variable.
If set, dconf will attempt to open the named profile, aborting if that fails.
If the environment variable is not set, it will attempt to open the profile named "user"
and if that fails, it will fall back to an internal hard-wired configuration.
```

I've added that file:

```
cat /etc/dconf/profile/user
user-db:user
system-db:local
```

Then I've put my lockdown file in /etc/dconf/db/local.d/lock

And finally I run dconf update

I had to logout and login again as I was using the hard-wired configuration.
Now it works.

Comment: Thank you. However, I cannot follow this through to any meaningful outcome. Which key/value combination did you lock, in order to test that your method was implemented successfully? I'm specifically interested in finding a way of locking the `automount` key to a value of false, in a global fashion, to prevent all but superuser access to externally attached media (in this case USB drives); the `automount` key is related to the `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling` schema.

Comment: Could you lock that key?

Comment: When you lock a key you'll use it's default value so to lock and modify the key you'd need to modify its default value.
Try adding a file like `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/my-defaults.gschema.override`:
`[org.gnome.desktop.media-handling]
automount=0`

Then run:
`glib-compile-schemas --strict /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

That will change the default value.

I was locking the proxy settings down:
`/system/proxy/mode
/system/proxy/autoconfig-url`