# how to disable set as wallpaper option in ubuntu 16 and above

Tags: 16.04

I  need to  restrict  local users from downloading images from internet  to  local  machine and with right click  set as wallpaper option they keep  resetting the wallpaper.   Need to  disable the set  as wallpaper option  in Ubuntu 16.

I  was able to  disable the option in 12 by editing `cat /usr/share/eog/eog-ui2.xml` but in Ubuntu 16 this file is not available.

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038184/how-to-lockdown-system-wide-settings-with-dconf

Comment: Nope it  didn't work  for us